# Last name printed twice on UK visa

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I’m traveling from US to UK for a seminar in two days with a Chinese passport, and just got the UK visa. But they printed my last name twice on the vignette, with all other informations correct.There is simply not enough time for me to send the passport back. Would I be able to board the plane(United) and go into the UK? Thank you for your time! I literally don’t know what to do anymore.

Comment: What did your visa application centre say about this when yoy contacted them? https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk/getting-a-decision-on-your-application